# Check Connection on iPhone

Tags: iphone, connection

I'm trying to check my iPhone-app for internet connection, I always get this error message:

*** +[Connection isConnected]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3bcd500

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[Connection isConnected]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3bcd500'

I use this example:
http://www.xprogress.com/post-40-iphone-internet-connection-check-wifi-3g-edge-something-like-reachability-h/

Can someone help me and assist me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `Connection.m` into your project?

Comment: Hello, yes i add Connection.m and connection.h into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get a warning that Connection is undefined or may not respond to selector when compiling?

Comment: Hello. The app crashes after execution following line: 
if ([Connection isConnected]).

If I debug the return value like: 
NSLog(@"%@",[Connection isConnected]) i get the right "YES" return value.

But i don't know why the app crashes.